# R^2 in random forest, using cforest()

Tags: r, random-forest

I would like to know how we can retrieve (or compute) R^2 when the function `cforest()` from the package `party` is used. The function `randomForest()` from the package of the same name returns a coefficient of determination, while `cforest()` does not. I read here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7357/manually-calculated-r2-doesnt-match-up-with-randomforest-r2-for-testing that R^2 is computed using the following formula in the package `randomForest()`:

```
R2<-1 - sum((y-predicted)^2)/sum((y-mean(y))^2) # y is the actual value
```

However, when I compare the R^2 derived from `randomForest()` and `cforest()` , I find a huge difference:

```
#### Minimal reproducible example ####

### Vectors ###

ARTICLE<-c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No")

COMPSYNT<-c("NP", "NP", "DetPoss", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", 
    "NP", "NP", "NP", "PronPers", "NP", "PronForm", "NP", "NP", "NP", "PronForm", "NP", "PronForm", "NP", "PronForm", "PronForm", 
    "NP", "PronPers", "PronForm", "NP", "DetPoss", "NP", "PronForm", "NFClau", "PronForm", "NP", "NP", "NP", "PronForm", "PronForm", "PronForm", 
    "NP", "NP", "NP", "PronForm", "PronForm", "NP", "NP", "PronForm", "PronForm", "NP", "PronForm", "PronForm", "NP", "NFClau", "NP", 
    "PronForm", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "PronForm", "PronForm", "NP", "NP", "NP", "PronForm", "NP", "PronForm", 
    "NP", "PronForm", "NFClau", "PronForm", "NP", "NP", "NFClau", "PronForm", "NP", "NP", "NP", "PronForm", "PronForm", "PronForm", "NP", 
    "PronForm", "NP", "NP", "PronForm", "PronForm", "PronForm", "NP", "PronForm", "PronPers", "NP", "NP")
    
POSITION<-c("Fin", "Fin", "Med", "Med", "Fin", "Fin", "Fin", "Fin", "Fin", 
    "Fin", "Med", "Fin", "Init", "Fin", "Med", "Fin", "Fin", "Fin", "Init", "Fin", "Init", "Init", "Init", "Init", 
    "Fin", "Fin", "Fin", "Fin", "Init", "Init", "Init", "Fin", "Init", "Init", "Fin", "Fin", "Init", "Init", "Init", 
    "Fin", "Fin", "Med", "Med", "Init", "Init", "Fin", "Fin", "Init", "Fin", "Fin", "Fin", "Fin", "Med", "Init", 
    "Init", "Med", "Fin", "Fin", "Init", "Init", "Med", "Init", "Init", "Fin", "Fin", "Init", "Init", "Init", "Init", 
    "Fin", "Fin", "Med", "Init", "Fin", "Fin", "Med", "Init", "Fin", "Fin", "Fin", "Init", "Init", "Fin", "Init", 
    "Init", "Fin", "Fin", "Init", "Init", "Init", "Fin", "Init", "Fin", "Fin", "Init")

COMPTYPE<-c("Abstr_1", 
    "Conc", "Hum", "Abstr_2", "Hum", "Hum", "Conc", "Hum", "Hum", "Hum", "Hum", "Hum", "Hum", "Hum", "Conc", "Hum", 
    "Hum", "Hum", "Hum", "Abstr_2", "Hum", "Hum", "Hum", "Hum", "Abstr_1", "Conc", "Abstr_1", "Conc", "Conc", "Abstr_1", "Conc", 
    "Abstr_2", "Hum", "Abstr_1", "Abstr_1", "Conc", "Conc", "Plant", "Hum", "Conc", "Abstr_2", "Conc", "Abstr_1", "Abstr_1", "Abstr_1", "Hum", 
    "Abstr_1", "Conc", "Hum", "Abstr_1", "Abstr_2", "Abstr_1", "Abstr_2", "Conc", "Hum", "Abstr_1", "Conc", "Abstr_1", "Hum", "Abstr_1", "Abstr_1", 
    "Hum", "Abstr_2", "Conc", "Abstr_1", "Conc", "Hum", "Conc", "Abstr_1", "Conc", "Abstr_1", "Abstr_2", "Conc", "Conc", "Hum", "Abstr_2", 
    "Conc", "Abstr_2", "Abstr_2", "Conc", "Abstr_2", "Conc", "Abstr_1", "Abstr_1", "Abstr_1", "Abstr_2", "Hum", "Hum", "Conc", "Abstr_2", "Abstr_1", 
    "Hum", "Abstr_2", "Conc", "Hum")

SUBSTYPE<-c("Repl", 
    "Repl", "Repl", "Contr", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Comp", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", 
    "Comp", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Contr", "Contr", "Contr", 
    "Contr", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Contr", "Contr", 
    "Contr", "Repl", "Contr", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Contr", "Contr", "Repl", "Contr", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Contr", "Contr", 
    "Repl", "Contr", "Repl", "Contr", "Repl", "Repl", "Contr", "Contr", "Contr", "Contr", "Contr", "Contr", "Contr", "Contr", "Contr", 
    "Contr", "Repl", "Repl", "Comp", "Repl", "Repl", "Repl", "Contr", "Repl", "Contr", "Contr", "Repl", "Repl", "Contr", "Contr", 
    "Repl", "Contr", "Repl", "Repl")

VARIANT<-c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
    "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
    "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
    "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
    "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
    "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2")
    
PERIOD<-c("1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", 
    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
    "4", "4")
    
PRED<-c(0.9479936898, 0.919449515, 0.9419154421, 0.5983387557, 
    0.6095731951, 0.6095731951, 0.919449515, 0.6095731951, 0.6095731951, 
    0.6095731951, 0.7030330529, 0.7525290886, 0.5973901173, 0.7525290886, 
    0.8111631081, 0.7758242732, 0.655754515, 0.7758242732, 0.3617200806, 
    0.204189421, 0.3617200806, 0.4091156245, 0.3617200806, 0.3617200806, 
    0.1909593012, 0.111197398, 0.1317200524, 0.1401576975, 0.3357625661, 
    0.0354262613, 0.3251898421, 0.0026529555, 0.3617200806, 0.1277255725, 
    0.1909593012, 0.1401576975, 0.0920054464, 0.0826276571, 0.3617200806, 
    0.1401576975, 0.204189421, 0.1362205175, 0.1076221699, 0.1021952872, 
    0.0354262613, 0.2225893662, 0.013977198, 0.0920054464, 0.2225893662, 
    0.1317200524, 0.1170159378, 0.1909593012, 0.0025081381, 0.0223554982, 
    0.3617200806, 0.0538830716, 0.1401576975, 0.1909593012, 0.4091156245, 
    0.0354262613, 0.0538830716, 0.3617200806, 0.0054761797, 0.1401576975, 
    0.051214367, 0.1171345461, 0.3617200806, 0.0223554982, 0.0141969626, 
    0.0331976869, 0.4525577246, 0.0023048079, 0.0103973282, 0.0331976869, 
    0.2786798396, 0.0025693648, 0.0119143655, 0.3508813284, 0.3508813284, 
    0.1910649906, 0.1038908339, 0.1222175396, 0.260972475, 0.0380847154, 
    0.1368486957, 0.0294733117, 0.3138516914, 0.4183846938, 0.1219226877, 
    0.0062738871, 0.0939148073, 0.4183846938, 0.3356194269, 0.3046349387, 
    0.4823614353)
    
DEV<-c(0.4479936898, 
    0.419449515, 0.4419154421, 0.0983387557, 0.1095731951, 0.1095731951, 
    0.419449515, 0.1095731951, 0.1095731951, 0.1095731951, 0.2030330529, 
    0.2525290886, 0.0973901173, 0.2525290886, 0.3111631081, 0.2758242732, 
    0.155754515, 0.2758242732, -0.1382799194, -0.295810579, -0.1382799194, 
    -0.0908843755, -0.1382799194, -0.1382799194, -0.3090406988, 
    -0.388802602, -0.3682799476, -0.3598423025, -0.1642374339, 
    -0.4645737387, -0.1748101579, -0.4973470445, -0.1382799194, 
    -0.3722744275, -0.3090406988, -0.3598423025, -0.4079945536, 
    -0.4173723429, -0.1382799194, -0.3598423025, -0.295810579, 
    -0.3637794825, -0.3923778301, -0.3978047128, -0.4645737387, 
    -0.2774106338, -0.486022802, -0.4079945536, -0.2774106338, 
    -0.3682799476, -0.3829840622, -0.3090406988, -0.4974918619, 
    -0.4776445018, -0.1382799194, -0.4461169284, -0.3598423025, 
    -0.3090406988, -0.0908843755, -0.4645737387, -0.4461169284, 
    -0.1382799194, -0.4945238203, -0.3598423025, -0.448785633, 
    -0.3828654539, -0.1382799194, -0.4776445018, -0.4858030374, 
    -0.4668023131, -0.0474422754, -0.4976951921, -0.4896026718, 
    -0.4668023131, -0.2213201604, -0.4974306352, -0.4880856345, 
    -0.1491186716, -0.1491186716, -0.3089350094, -0.3961091661, 
    -0.3777824604, -0.239027525, -0.4619152846, -0.3631513043, 
    -0.4705266883, -0.1861483086, -0.0816153062, -0.3780773123, 
    -0.4937261129, -0.4060851927, -0.0816153062, -0.1643805731, 
    -0.1953650613, -0.0176385647)

### Combining the vectors into a data frame ###

mydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(ARTICLE, COMPSYNT, COMPTYPE, DEV, PERIOD, POSITION, PRED, SUBSTYPE, VARIANT))
mydata$DEV<-as.numeric(as.character(mydata$DEV))
mydata$PRED<-as.numeric(as.character(mydata$PRED))

### First random forest on my data: 'randomForest' (package: 'randomForest') ###
set.seed(123)
mydata.rf1<-randomForest(DEV ~ ARTICLE + COMPSYNT + POSITION + COMPTYPE + SUBSTYPE + PERIOD, data=mydata, ntree=2000, mtry=2, importance=TRUE)
print(mydata.rf1)

Call:
 randomForest(formula = DEV ~ ARTICLE + COMPSYNT + POSITION +      COMPTYPE + SUBSTYPE + PERIOD, data = mydata, ntree = 2000,      mtry = 2, importance = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 2000
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

          Mean of squared residuals: 0.0110483
                    % Var explained: 83.33
## MSE = 0.0110483
## pseudo-R^2 = 0.8333

### Second random forest on my data: 'cforest' (package: 'party') ###

set.seed(123)
mydata.rf2<-cforest(DEV ~ ARTICLE + COMPSYNT + POSITION + COMPTYPE + SUBSTYPE + PERIOD, data=mydata, controls=cforest_unbiased(ntree=2000, mtry=2))
oob.pred<-predict(mydata.rf2, type="response", OOB=TRUE)
residual<-DEV-oob.pred
mse<-sum(residual^2)/length(DEV)
pseudo.R2<-1-mse/var(DEV)

## MSE = 0.0380004
## pseudo-R^2 = 0.4327
```

I can't seem to figure out why there is so big a difference between my two R^2-values. My questions are the following:

1. Can the formula for R^2 above be used when we use `cforest()`? If yes, why do I get such different values?
2. Is there an easier way to retrieve R^2 when we use `cforest()`?

Comment: Just a note, `cbind()` will create a matrix. If you use `mydata <- data.frame(ARTICLE, COMPSYNT, COMPTYPE, ...)` instead of `as.data.frame(cbind(ARTICLE, COMPSYNT, COMPTYPE, ...))` then you won't need to do the type conversion on your next two lines.

Comment: Thanks for your 2 cents :). I don't know why I used a two-step combination instead of the simplest one.

Comment: As for your question - yes you can use that formula for R^2 (though it's not clear whether you want to use OOB predictions or not if you want to compare to the `randomForest`). I don't know of an easier way to get R^2 when using `cforest` - but your way seems very simple - it's just two quick lines. You could make your own function that does it... The reason the R^2 is different between the two models is that that models are different, and the first one is much better. Look at the MSE for each model, or plot the predictions vs the true values. The first model is better, thus has higher R^2.

Comment: Thank you Gregor. Actually I read somewhere that OOB predictions were used in randomForest, so I used predict(..., OOB=TRUE) on the cforest object in order to get 'comaprable' results. Or am I doing something wrong? Do you think, then, that I should prefer the randomForest model over the other? BTW, setting OOB=FALSE does not change my cforest R^2 that much: 0.4817 instead of 0.4327

Comment: OOB predictions are good to look at, but I'm not sure what the `randomForest` R^2 is using - if you're comparing models you should compare OOB for both or not OOB for both. And yes, I prefer models that have better performance.